# UITableView under transparent navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I'm trying to layout a tableview in a UIViewController with a transparent navigationBar. I already accomplished this, using this code on my custom UINavigationController:

```
navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
```

On my storyboard I set my tableView with its edges pinned to the safe area, except for the top one, who is pinned to the top of the super view.

Problem is that my tableView is not starting at the top of the screen but as if the navigation bar is still opaque. I check the tableView insets and all are zero. What I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Make sure you have `edgesForExtendedLayout` is at least containing `.top`. i.e set on `viewDidLoad` `edgesForExtendedLayout = [.top]` and check

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to disable the scroll view insets adjustment.

`contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior` is available from iOS11 so you can check the availability like in this code:

```
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) 
{
    self.tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentNever;
} 
else 
{
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
}
```

Comment: Yeah!, this worked :) Seems `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` is deprecated and does nothing on iOS 11.0, so `tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior` is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5.8.1 variant :

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
   tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
} else {
   automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
}
```